# Typeorm, how to model OneToManyrelation with composit key

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

I am a little confused on how to model a relation with composit keys. I have:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'labels' })
export class Label {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  locale: string
  @PrimaryColumn()
  labelId: string
  @Column()
  labelValue: string
  @Column()
  entityId: string
}
```

now how do I have to model the relationship in an other entity? I tried the following with no success, unfortunately I am not used to annotations in javascript

```
@Entity({ name: 'country' })
export class Country {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ length: 2 })
  alpha2: string

  @OneToMany(
    type => Label,
    label => {label.labelId, label.locale},
    {eager:true}
  )
  name: Label
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Kind regards
athias

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, try to update your entities as the following:

```
@Unique(['labelId', 'name'])
@Entity({ locale: 'labels' })
export class Label {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  locale: string
  @Column()
  labelId: string
  @ManyToOne( type => Country,
  country => country.labels)
  country: Country // ManyToOne should refer to an entity (Country)
  @Column()
  labelValue: string
  @Column()
  entityId: string
}

@Entity({ name: 'country' })
export class Country {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ length: 2 })
  alpha2: string

  @OneToMany(
    type => Label,
    label => label.country
  )
  labels: Label[] //One to many relationship is always  an array
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately that is not what I am looking for. Labels is some kind of I18N Table so having `locale` as only primary key will not work, that is why I have composit keys because you will have e.g. locale `de` multiple times with label values Deutschland/Germany/Chines Word for Germany etc....

Comment: @MathiasMaerker I Update my answer, I think you need to add an Unique constraint to perform that